# What is the best way to locate element if the app is multi languages?

Tags: java, android, xpath, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm trying to automate test cases of an android app which is implemented in Both Arabic and English.

I'm using `appium`, and `AndroidDriver`. Also I'm using `Xpath` in major tests.
When I switch to arabic test cases didn't work anymore.
Any suggestion?

Comment: You should depends on ids,classname if those are unique. Xpath could create issue in multilanguages.

Comment: The id is the same when i write it in username it is ok.
But in password field i don't know where is the problem it clicks into eye icon instead of sending password in .send keys()
even if the id is the same in both langauges !

Comment: is it solved, ur password issue?..if not send , attach the code for username and password

Comment: I solve it by a way that is very strange, in fact, what i do in password filed to go there and clear text (or sendkeys with empty password or even not empty because the first time no things is been written (in Arabic Version) ) than go to username and sendkeys then go back to password and send keys again.

Note : The actual behaviour when i want to enter username then password ==> username it's ok, but password still empty...

Comment: i dont get u ;) if you could initiate a chat for this, it would be helpful

Comment: Ohh i'll explain more, see my answer it contains the code i'm using in Arabic Version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@karthick : this is the code i'm using it works fine. But if i didn't clear password field before start writing password it will be always empty even after sending keys.

```
public void Credentials(String username,String password)
{ 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.ScrollView[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText[1]")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.ScrollView[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText[2]")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.ScrollView[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText[2]")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.ScrollView[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.TextView[1]")).click();

}
```

Comment: I would suggest to defing the xpath as webElemnts before performing any sendkeys actions since they are big to traverse

Comment: You are right, but driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.ScrollView[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText[2]")).clear();
    while clearing fild which is already empty it taps on eye icon !!

Comment: Its hard to comment without screenshot of the page and uiautomator hierarchy

Answer (score 2):

The best test tool I used is rational robot. it will catch the component id instead of the image. and 100% correct catching.

For your case, I think you need to separate the functional test and i18n test. the function only test with English, and have special cased for the translation.

Comment: How it catch the same component as in English as in Arabic? And in Arabic version all screen, fields and data is reverted in the other direction?

Answer (score 1):

Try to figure out the `id or class` of the element by using `monitor.bat`, it should be inside your Android sdk. Without seeing your app code it will be difficult to say why it is not clicking in the password field. But if you give the correct Id it should always work irrespective of the language the app is in.

Comment: Tried appium inspector in ios